# Tab character not working in Python IDLE

Tags: python, output, control-characters

I'm trying to implement a tab space using the '\t' in my code (see code below), but at print time it outputs '\t, char'. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
paranoid_android = "Marvin"
letters = list(paranoid_android)
for char in letters:
    print('\t', char)
```

Answer (score 5):

You are probably using Python 2.x.  Remove the parentheses.  `print` is a statement in Python 2.x, not a function.  With parentheses, Python 2.x will think you are printing a tuple.

```
paranoid_android = "Marvin"
letters = list(paranoid_android)
for char in letters:
    print('\t', char)
for char in letters:
    print '\t', char
```

Output:

```
('\t', 'M')
('\t', 'a')
('\t', 'r')
('\t', 'v')
('\t', 'i')
('\t', 'n')
    M
    a
    r
    v
    i
    n
```

You can also add the following to the top of a Python 2.x script to Python 2.x work like Python 3.x, where `print` is a function:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

Comment: Thanks Mark. You are absolutely correct. I just realized it only works with Python 3.5.2 and not Python 2.x.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to use \t with Python version 2.7 and as a result it was outputting as \t as a string. I then proceeded to use a version Python 3.5.2 and it worked properly.

Thanks

Comment: Instead of writing your own answer repeating what others have suggested, simply accept their answer as the correct one, and leave a comment under it if you wish.